# More than +200 reputation in a day: how is this allowed?

Tags: discussion, reputation

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, I didn't receive any bounties but I still got more than 200 reputation! What does it mean?

It has also happened to me before but I thought that was because I edited a lot of posts, but as you can clearly see, I didn't do any of that today.

Comment: How many accepted answers and bounties did you get? SERIOUSLY? :O

Comment: Darn it. I lost an upvoted after that. So 730. Here is the graph: https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind?tab=reputation&sort=graph&StartDate=2011-06-24%2007:37:05Z

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/712603/david-robinson holds the current record with 1550. And this SQL can be used for that: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/110083/most-rep-gained-in-a-single-day

Comment: My God that's impressive! It really is!

Comment: Naaah. Only 50 from upvotes and 3x 500 bounty. He was slacking that day after he got the 1st 500 :=)

Comment: And I'm bragging to my friends about 211 :p

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The +15 for an accepted answer doesn't count towards the rep cap. Neither does the +2 for accepting an answer.

[What is the reputation cap and how can I hit it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32161/270345)

Comment: Bounties are also exempt.